# app is crashing when i am inserting background image

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

my app is crashing when I am inserting an image and I am not getting log report too when I am writing `android:background="@drawable/logo"` my app is crashing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/logo"
    tools:context="com.android.spotsdialog.MainActivity">   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: Try by unistalling the current build from device and do "clean build and rebuild options" and then install it on your device. Just remember you can catch the log in studio at the same time when your app will launch in device so just make sure you have selected your current app in the logcat with setting of "Show only selected application".

Comment: when i had kept my image in drawable folder it had worked but when i kept my image in drawable-v24 folder my app is crashing

Comment: perhaps it's causes by you did not declare the old API to support vector in the gradle

Comment: What is the size of the image in MB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you probably testing on lower API version then **API24**. So it will throw `ResourceNotFoundException` cause drawable does not exists for it .

So You have to have a copy of it normal drawable folder drawable . Or in all drawable-v24, drawable-v21 and drawable . put the drawable in all folder most importantly in `drawable`.
**drawable**
**drawable-v21**
**drawable-v24**

Answer (score 0):

please put crashing text or you can replace this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.android.spotsdialog.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
         />
</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: can you explain why OP use linear layout instead of relative layout and also tell me if OP set `android:background` on relative layout then why app is crashing ?. Instead of showing right track to OP you just put what u know why ?