# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07006e

Tags: android

Actually, I have no idea why I have this error.

Follows the code hoping that there is everything useful for a diagnosis.

The structure of the app is a standard `Navigation Drawer Activity` with a `Fragment` inside. The `Fragment` has a `RecyclerView`.

The device used is **Motorola XT1068 (Android 6.0, API 23)**.

**Logcat**

```
03-26 16:07:54.340 20272-20272/com.example.ves.gennaio3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ves.gennaio3, PID: 20272
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07006e
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
        at com.example.ves.gennaio3.models.RecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:38)
        at com.example.ves.gennaio3.models.RecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:17)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1166)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:851)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1172)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
        a
        03-26 16:07:55.215 15332-18804/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error -4 during AudioRecord native read
```

**Dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.ves.gennaio3;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements CardFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container)!=null) {
            if (savedInstanceState!=null) {return;}
            CardFragment cardFragment = new CardFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, cardFragment).commit();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }




        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

**CardFragment.java**

```
package com.example.ves.gennaio3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.ves.gennaio3.models.ItemObject;
import com.example.ves.gennaio3.models.RecyclerViewAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link CardFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link CardFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class CardFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public CardFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment CardFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static CardFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        CardFragment fragment = new CardFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card, container, false);
        rootView.setTag("CardFragment");

        List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), rowListItem);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(){

        List<ItemObject> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("United States", R.drawable.newyork));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Canada", R.drawable.canada));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("United Kingdom", R.drawable.uk));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Germany", R.drawable.germany));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Sweden", R.drawable.sweden));

        return allItems;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ves.gennaio3.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fragment_card.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ves.gennaio3.CardFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

**card_view_list.xml** (my `RecycleView` item layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/card_view">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/country_photo"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Nigeria"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:text="Get" />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.ves.gennaio3.models;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.ves.gennaio3.R;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by VES on 03/02/2018.
 */

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders>{

    private List<ItemObject> itemList;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_list, null);
        RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
        holder.countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
        holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }

}
```

**RecyclerViewHolders.java**

```
package com.example.ves.gennaio3.models;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.ves.gennaio3.R;

/**
 * Created by VES on 03/02/2018.
 */

public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public TextView countryName;
    public ImageView countryPhoto;
    public Button button;

    public RecyclerViewHolders(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        countryName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        countryPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
        button = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "questa è prova", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Country Position = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

**UPDATE**

One of the answers suggests that the problem could be related to getAllItems(). But resources invoked seem to be correctly loaded.

[image]

Comment: You have added whole lot of code but did not add most important part . The stacktrace . Add the log stacktrace .

Comment: @ADM you have right! updated :)

Comment: I can only guess . Seems like problem is in `RecyclerView` item layout . So Have a look at [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49462722/4168607) . Check weather you have same issue or not .

Comment: @ADM thanks but it looks right. :(

Comment: If issue is not resolved add `RecyclerView` item layout in question .

Comment: @ADM done :) :)

Comment: Well taking `onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:38)` as a reference . I suggest you should add `RecyclerViewAdapter.java` in question also point out whats on line number 38 . This looks like a lot of code in question . No worry just add it .

Comment: The problem looks like from the following line: `        holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());`. Check your `getAllItemList()` method. Probably you are giving incorrect drawable id.

Comment: Open up R.java and search for `0x7f07006e` that should give you the resource name this reference is mapping.

Comment: The screenshot shows v24 next to those resources, so they probably only exist in the v24 folder. Your phone is API23

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your problem is the wrong placement of resources(images).
You use (API 23) but resources for API 23 is null, because they only API 24 and up.

[image]

Now all images marked (v24) this means that they are in drawables-v24 just move in drawable

[image]

that'll solve your problem.

Comment: It was really helpful

Comment: this answer just saved my whole day and 2 days efforts

Comment: This too helped me. Thanks for demonstrating the underlined (v24) in the resources folder.

Answer (score 5):

maybe you have a resource in **drawable-v24** . just move them to **drawable**.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your issue is with this line:

```
holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
```

`itemList.get(position).getPhoto()` must return a valid ResId. (Refer to the [`ImageView` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)).

As you mention, `itemList` looks to be set up correctly. I suggest that you set a breakpoint at the above line and see what is being returned from `getPhoto()`. You should also be able to determine if this is the line causing your exception.

If that doesn't help, post `ItemObject` here so we can get a look at `getPhoto()` and maybe a couple of other things.

---

I just noticed the V24 by the drawables in the image you posted. I agree with Dennis K's comment that your phone is API23 and you have drawables for API 24+. Android will not select these drawables if the API level is less than API 24. If these drawables are suitable for API 23, move them to a folder that supports API 23.

See [Providing Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

> Platform Version (API level)   Examples:
>   v3
>   v4
>   v7
>   etc.
>
> The API level supported by the device. For example, v1 for API level 1 (devices with Android 1.0 or higher) and v4 for API level 4 (devices with Android 1.6 or higher). See the Android API levels document for more information about these values.

Comment: @Stefano, seems like moving resources form V24 to lower dimens should solve the issue, isn't it?

Comment: @azizbekian yes I have checked and this was the issue :) thanks!!