# Binary XML file line #19: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Tags: android, drawable

Note: My app is working fine on old device android 5.But i am geeting this problem in newer versions.Now i have added the code for login and spinner....
I think it may be the problem of density pixels of images..or placing the things in wrong places.I need time from experts.Kindly Solve my problem.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="512dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="98dp"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_new"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription,UnusedAttribute" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                style="auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tv_username"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/username"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tv_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    tools:inputType="textPassword|textVisiblePassword" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <Button   
                android:onClick="login"
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:text="@string/log_in"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#ffff" />
            <TextView
                android:textColor="#701212"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/forgot_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:popupBackground="?android:attr/textColorHighlightInverse"
            android:theme="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light"/>





    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:background="#701212"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#097779"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/designed_and_develop_by"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#730b72"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:text="@string/db_scholars"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

.
Thanks in advance

[image]

```
Process: com.example.muhammadobaid.sims, PID: 18834
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.muhammadobaid.sims/com.example.muhammadobaid.sims.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #98: Binary XML file line #98: Error inflating class Spinner
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3012)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1716)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6802)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #98: Binary XML file line #98: Error inflating class Spinner
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #98: Error inflating class Spinner
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable android:color/highlighted_text_material with resource ID #0x1060118
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/highlighted_text_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x1060118
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1015)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:791)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1019)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.<init>(PopupWindow.java:286)
        at android.widget.ColorPopupWindow.<init>(ColorPopupWindow.java:77)
        at android.widget.ColorListPopupWindow.createPopupWindow(ColorListPopupWindow.java:90)
        at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.<init>(ListPopupWindow.java:246)
        at android.widget.ColorListPopupWindow.<init>(ColorListPopupWindow.java:82)
        at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.<init>(Spinner.java:1202)
        at android.widget.Spinner.createDropdownPopup(Spinner.java:1333)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:294)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:222)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:172)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:195)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:166)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:147)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.<init>(AppCompatSpinner.java:132)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:115)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1016)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1073)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.muhammadobaid.sims.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:52)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6974)
09-30 22:57:56.275 18834-18834/com.example.muhammadobaid.sims E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2900)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3012)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1716)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6802)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
     **Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #19: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
        at** android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:183)
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:116)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1232)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1205)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:998)
            ... 44 more
```

Comment: check api for resources https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49477979/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-id-0x7f07006e/49858583#49858583

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoEbc.png

Comment: Share your `Spinner` xml code?

Comment: show your activity_login.xml

Comment: Login code added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$**NotFoundException**: `Drawable
>   android:color/highlighted_text_material` with resource ID #0x1060118

That's a `NotFoundException` which means it couldn't find such color-file anything in this path:

```
res/color/highlighted_text_material.xml
```

You should probably change this.

Also, I just saw that there is another issue with the `Spinner`:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #98: Binary XML file line #98: Error inflating class Spinner
```

I'm suspecting about this part:

```
android:popupBackground="?android:attr/textColorHighlightInverse"
```

Try changing the color to **a not private resource**.

The another issue is:

```
<item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
```

Add what it says to your `drawable` file: **requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable**

Comment: I just removed...            android:popupBackground="?android:attr/textColorHighlightInverse"

Comment: Reputation is less than 15..my vote is recorded but not shown....My heart gives you the Vote!!