# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: Binary XML file line #64: Binary XML file line #64: Error inflating class TextView

Tags: android

I am having recently this error while trying to run my android application on my cell phone, note that previously the application was working very well on the same cell phone without having this error.
The error I am getting is the following:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my package name}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: Binary XML file line #64: Error inflating class TextView
```

And my XML file looks like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lcocenter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LCo center"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#7BD7F4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lcocenter"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="A resource of mute competencies,\nWe recognize in you\n\nSilence of problems, notions, intentions,\nWe acknowledge in you\n\nA service of exchange,\nWe offer you\n\nTo open up your package of experience,\nWe invite you\n\nOur work is to attend to you\n\nThank you"
        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_calendar"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/lightBlue" />

    <ImageView
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/youtube"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/youtube"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Youtblink"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Muktatafaty"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/youtube"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listview"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColorLink="#172F95"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/rateus"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ratereview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rateustxt"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rateustxt"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rate us"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listview"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#172F95"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: the xml layout works fine on my end too could share the activity code if you are setting text into the textViews

Comment: The line number "#64" causing the error in the XML file points to the "@+id/Youtblink" TextView. My activity code is the following:  
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ytbtxt=findViewById(R.id.Youtblink);
        ytbtxt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());  The error also point on " setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);" this line in the activity code @MalikSaifullah

Comment: Still working fine on my end. 
Try Invalidating cache & Restart and also comment out TextView One by one and debug which TextView is messing it up.

Comment: I have tried it on another device, worked without any problem! But still getting the same error on the previous one! @MalikSaifullah

Comment: Please share the both phone Api Levels i am ball parking here api level may confirm or not my approach.

Comment: The well working device Api level is 28 and the device causing the error Api level is 23

Comment: Okay try this. Check all of your drawables are in which folder are they in `drawableV24` ( it means it will not work under api level 24 ) if all are v24 copy paste them in `drawable` folder and it should work below 24 as well.

Comment: You can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49477979/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-id-0x7f07006e)

Comment: All my drawables are in drawable folder! My app worked very well yesterday on the device causing the error (Api 23) , but suddenly today it starts to cause this error

Comment: Could you update the complete Logcat error rather than one liner. Thanks.